# Linq Nullable object must have a value. errors in .NET 6 and EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core, lambda

I have this code:

```
IQueryable<WinnerClassExtend> dataList = 
from Class in _context.AllClass
join Winner in _context.AllWinners on Class.ClassId equals Winner.ClassId

let Extend = new { Winner, Class }
group Extend by Class.ClassId into Group

select new WinnerClassExtend
{
    Class = Group.Select(x => x.Class).FirstOrDefault(),
    NumberOfWinnerinClass = Group.Select(x => x.Winner).Count()
};

var count = dataList.Count();
```

I try to get the count of `IQueryable` in just like what I did in .net framework and entity framework, but it seems not to be working... and I get an error

> Nullable object must have a value

I have no idea what's wrong with it, and I also try using this,

```
IQueryable<WinnerClassExtend> dataList =
     _context.AllClass
    .Join(_context.AllWinners , Class => Class.ClassId, Winner => Winner.ClassId, (Class, Winner) => new { Class, Winner })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Class.ClassId })
    .Select(x => new WinnerClassExtend
    {
        Class = x.Select(i => i.Class).FirstOrDefault(),
        NumberOfWinnerinClass = x.Select(i => i.Winner).Count()
    });

var count = dataList.Count();
```

And it returns the same...

I have read some issue of this error, but it seems unlike the same problem, Can anyone help?

Comment: Use a navigation property, not join, and it all becomes very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var dataList = 
    from Class in _context.AllClass
    select new WinnerClassExtend
    {
        Class = Class,
        NumberOfWinnerinClass = _context.AllWinners.Where(w => w.ClassId == Class.ClassId).Count()
    };

var count = dataList.Count();
```

Or another one:

```cs
var grouped = 
    from Winner in _context.AllWinners
    group Winner by Class.ClassId into Group
    select new 
    {
        ClassId = Group.Key,
        NumberOfWinnerinClass = Group.Count()
    };

var dataList = 
    from Class in _context.AllClass
    join g in grouped on ClassId.ClassId equals g.ClassId
    select new WinnerClassExtend
    {
        Class = Class,
        NumberOfWinnerinClass = g.NumberOfWinnerinClass
    };

var count = dataList.Count();
```

In both cases compare execution plan.

Comment: It will work! But it there any performance issue in this way?
It looks like Subquery in T-SQL

Comment: Do you know why I can't use my way with join, group by and count?
Beacause of the changes of dotnet core?

Comment: Performance issues, probably. But have you tried to compare  execution plan with old framework query? And yes everything has been changed because LINQ translator is different. I can rewrite this query to use joins, but it will be complex query with grouping and three joins.

Comment: Can you show me with that? I would like to know how it would work with join and group now...

Comment: Updated answer, well only one join.

Comment: If you think that this is the right answer, mark it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need a left outer join:

```
var dataList =
    from c in _context.AllClass
    join w in _context.AllWinners on c.ClassId equals w.ClassId into winners
    select new WinnerClassExtend
    {
        Class = c,
        NumberOfWinnerinClass = winners.Count()
    };

var count = dataList.Count();
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried this...
But It will throw Error "The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. "

Comment: This query is non working analogue of my first query. Non working because EF Core has serious limitations with GroupJoin.